# stackexchange APIの/me/inbox/unreadのsite parameterが無視されている?

Tags: バグ, サポート

StackExchange APIの`/me/inbox/unread`を見ると`Per-Site Methods`となっていて`site` parameterが必ず必要ということになっています。
しかし、実際に実行してみると`askubuntu`を指定したにもかかわらずスタックオーバーフロー Meta(日本語版)の内容が表示されています。
なぜなのでしょうか?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`/users/{id}/inbox/unread`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/user-unread-inbox) は `Per-Site Method` ですが、`Network Method` である [`/inbox/unread`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/inbox-unread) へのエイリアスのようです。

> This method is effectively an alias for /inbox/unread.

こういったエイリアスがあるのは変かも知れませんが、そういう API なのでしょう。
`/me/inbox/unread` も同じ事情で、[`inbox`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/inbox-item) というのは常に、"Global Inbox" の事なのだと思います。

Comment: siteにどこを指定しても同じということですね
ただ、別になくてもいいものを必須にしているのでかなりややこしい(使うときに困惑する)のではないかと思いますが... この辺りが良くなっていく予定はあるのでしょうか?